# ClassNotFoundException when using PowerMock - Android Junit

Tags: java, android, junit, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to write some tests that use PowerMock/PowerMockito but for some reason, I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException on my Test class when ever I try to run a test in that class.  Here are my app.gradle powerMockito statements:

```
androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock:1.6.6'
androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
```

Here is the start of my testing class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SettingsView.class)
public class SettingsTests {

  private SettingsView view;
```

...

Here is the stacktrace that I receive:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.SettingsTests
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:161)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:48)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:111)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:71)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:77)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:40)
at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:81)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.classes(TestRequestBuilder.java:789)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:753)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:354)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:260)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.app.SettingsTests. Reason: com.app.SettingsTests
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:284)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:192)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:77)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 27 more
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: com.app.SettingsTests
at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:452)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:262)
... 31 more
```

Does anyone know what could potentially be causing this? Junit version is 4.12

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works on android or not.  I had similar issue on my web project and overriding javaassist dependency worked for me. Give it a try.

```
testCompile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.18.2-GA'
```

Comment: I haven't worked with android. Found this one. Might be helpful to you. https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/776